# Problem registering protocols with associated types using swinject

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, swinject

I wanted to develop an application which uses repository patterns using core data and realm. I want to resolve protocol according to my needs. Purpose is to inject a generic core data repository / realm repository protocol in the assembly.

Problem occurs on this line saying **`Protocol 'SleepRepositoryProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`**

```
func assemble(container: Container) {
    container.register(SleepRepositoryProtocol.self) { r in
        CoreDataSleepRepository(persistentContainer:r.resolve(NSPersistentContainer.self)!)
        }.inObjectScope(.container)
}
```

I am unable to inject sleep repository protocol because of using generic (associated type) properties. How can I solve this problem?

Additionally,thank you very much for your response. It really helped me a lot. I have one more issue with this.

var repository: SleepRepositoryProtocol

```
var items: [SleepEntity]?

private let assembler: Assembler

init(assembler: Assembler) {
    self.assembler = assembler
    
    repository = assembler.resolver.resolve(SleepRepositoryProtocol.self)!
}
```

This gives me error "Protocol 'SleepRepositoryProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements" and I don't know how to resolve my SleepRepositoryProtocol.

Comment: I never used swinject, but this error means that you cannot instantiate a type using a protocol with associated types. Instead, instantiate the specific type conforming to it.

Answer (score 1):

This error is a classic:

```
    container.register(SleepRepositoryProtocol.self) { r in
```

is forbidden because `SleepRepositoryProtocol` is a [Protocol with Associated Type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID189).

what you would need is for the `assemble(container:)` method to be generic and declared this way for example:

```
func assemble<Repository: SleepRepositoryProtocol>(container: Container, ofType type:Repository) {
```

but since it's part of [Swinject's Assembly Protocol](https://github.com/Swinject/Swinject/blob/405935d51acdb9db6f920e6099328a92fb420a4b/Sources/Assembly.swift) it is not an option and you need to find another place to put the [Generic Type Constraint](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID186).

In your case it can be the enclosing type eg.:

```
class MyClass<Repository: SleepRepositoryProtocol>: Assembly {
    func assemble(container: Container) {
        container.register(Repository.self) { r in
          CoreDataSleepRepository(persistentContainer:r.resolve(NSPersistentContainer.self)!)
        }
        .inObjectScope(.container)
    }
}
```

#### Edit

you cannot just write :

```
var repository: SleepRepositoryProtocol
```

Once you add `associatedtype` in you protocol you can **never** use it like a normal type, only as a [Generic Type Constraint](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html#ID186)

So if I update `MyClass` with your other properties:

```
class MyClass<Repository: SleepRepositoryProtocol>: Assembly {
    var repository: Repository

    var items: [SleepEntity]?

    private let assembler: Assembler

    init(assembler: Assembler) {
        self.assembler = assembler
        
        repository = assembler.resolver.resolve(Repository.self)!
    }

    func assemble(container: Container) {
        container.register(Repository.self) { r in
          CoreDataSleepRepository(persistentContainer:r.resolve(NSPersistentContainer.self)!)
        }
        .inObjectScope(.container)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It really helped me a lot. I have one more issue with this. This gives me error and I don't know how to resolve my SleepRepositoryProtocol.                                                                                                        var repository: RepositoryProtocol
    
    var items: [SleepEntity]?
    
    private let assembler: Assembler
    
    init(assembler: Assembler) {
        self.assembler = assembler
        
        repository = assembler.resolver.resolve(RepositoryProtocol.self)!
    }.

Comment: hard to read in a comment. you should edit your question or even better start another one

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I have updated my sleep repository and didn't use generic on it. That solved my problem and injection worked really well.

Comment: Great. I'd say as a rule you should upvote useful answers and accept the one that provide you with the best solution ;)